# Is my declared array size interring with my search?

Tags: java, arrays, search

I have a program utilize swing GUI and new sort algorithms and searches. My sorts work fine however when trying to search for numbers I have it give a message whether it has been found or not. However rather saying its found when the number exists, it says its not found.Also for some reason it only says that 0 is found at index 4.

```
static int Numbers[]=new int[0];

private static class ButtonHandler implements ActionListener
 {
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
     {
            //get data
            String data = txtInput.getText();

            //parse for numerical value
           int  numGenerate = Integer.parseInt(data); 
           int Numbers[]=new int[numGenerate];
           String command = e.getActionCommand(); 
         if (command.equals("Sort"))
         { 

           String unSortedData="";

           //ouput unsoted data
           for (int x=0;x<=Numbers.length-1;x++)
           {
               Numbers[x]=(int)(Math.random()*2001)-1000;
               unSortedData+=(Numbers[x]+",");

           }
            txtUnsorted.setText(unSortedData);




             if (btnQuickSort.isSelected())
            {
                QuickSort(Numbers,0,Numbers.length-1);
            }
             if (btnMergeSort.isSelected())
            {
                MergeSort(Numbers,0,Numbers.length-1);
            } 
            if (btnInsertionSort.isSelected())
            {
                InsertionSort(Numbers);
            } 
            if (btnSelectionSort.isSelected())
            {
                SelectionSort(Numbers);
            } 
            if (btnShellSort.isSelected())
            {
                ShellSort(Numbers);
            } 
            if (btnShakerSort.isSelected())
            {
                 ShakerSort(Numbers);
            }
            generated=true;




         }
               if (command.equals("Search"))
         {
                //get data
                String data2 = txtSearch.getText();
                //parse for numerical value
                int  FindNum = Integer.parseInt(data2);

                if (generated==true)
                {
                            int counter=0;

                            for (int x=0;x<Numbers.length;x++)
                            {
                              if (Numbers[x]==FindNum)
                              {
                                lblSearch.setText("Status: Found "+ FindNum+ "at index "+ counter );
                              }
                             counter++;   
                            }

                }
                else
                {

                    lblSearch.setText("Status:Error! Enter or sort a number");
                }
         }



     }
 }
```

Comment: Inside your action handler you create a new `Numbers` array but you only fill it with random numbers inside the 'sort' branch. If the user selects 'search' then the array will be filled with zeros. Presumably it's finding zero in index 4 because that's the last item in the array.

Comment: Any idea how to get the numbers array with the random numbers to be searched rather than the zeros?

Comment: I'll add an answer for you on that

Answer (score 0):

At the moment you are only populating the array with random numbers if you run the 'search' component. I suggest splitting the generation and the two operations into separate methods:

```
private int[] randomNumbers(int size) {
    Random random = new Random();
    int[] numbers = new int[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++)
        numbers[i] = random.nextInt(2000) - 1000;
    unsortedData = Arrays.toString(numbers);
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    int[] numbers = randomNumbers(Integer.valueOf(txtInput.getText());
    switch(e.getActionCommand()) {
        case "sort":
            ...
            break;
        case "search":
            ...
            break;
    }
}
```

Note that there is a simpler way of getting an array of random integers:

```
int[] numbers = random.ints(size, -2000, 2000).toArray();
```

But I'm assuming you're not using streams yet.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion and no I'm not using streams yet I'm only in high school. However I seemed to have fixed my issue. Instead of doing int Numbers[]=new int[numGenerate]; I did Numbers =new int[numGenerate];. I don't understand how that fixed it but it worked.If you could kindly explain why would be greatly appreciated! Any How thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

In actionPerformed(), a new local variable named "Numbers" is defined by "int Numbers[]=new int[numGenerate]" which masks global variable "Numbers".
And when you delete "int" and use "Numbers =new int[numGenerate]", the global variable "Numbers" can be used here and program works as you expect.